# How many five-digit numbers are there that have exactly two odd digits in their decimal notation?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I thought that in the first place you can choose 9 out of 10 numbers (all but zero) then in the second place choose 4 out of 5.
Or the second option in the first place can be 4 out of 5 odd numbers, in the second and third places we choose odd.
it seems to me that I am confused in these combinations, I don’t understand how to calculate, given that zero cannot be the first

Comment: first calculate the number of 5 digit numbers without worrying about leading zeros, subtract from this the number of 4 digit numbers (again without worrying about leading zeros)

Comment: Another option is to consider cases, depending on whether the leading digit is even or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, take the $\binom{5}{2}5^25^3$ numbers with at most five digits, and subtract the numbers with at most four digits, that is $\binom{5}{2}5^5-\binom{4}{2}5^4=44\cdot 5^4=27500$.

Comment: This seem to double-count cases when you have repeated odd number (7 and 7) or if you have repeats in even numbers. When you choose $5 \choose 2$ they'd be considered as 2 separate numbers.

Comment: I think that double counting is not an issue here, because I choose to distinct *positions*, not *numbers*. If I would choose $5\cdot 4$, I would count twice, thus the division by $2$ in $\binom{5}{2}$. Having chosen the two positions, I iterate through all combinations with $5^2$. This counts every combination once, also pairs, say $(7,7)$, once.

Answer (score 1):

The (moderately) less elegant approach that the OP (i.e. original poster) attempted is also feasible.

If the leftmost digit is odd, then the number of satisfying digits is

$$5 \times \binom{4}{1} \times 5^4. \tag1 $$

If the leftmost digit is even, then the number of satisfying digits is

$$4 \times \binom{4}{2} \times 5^4. \tag2 $$

Adding the expressions in (1) and (2) above gives

$$5^4 \times \left[ ~(5 \times 4) + (4 \times 6) ~\right] = 27500.$$